# Docker exec only contains results of last build step

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I see a lot of advice for troubleshooting telling people to run `docker exec -t <container_id> /bin/bash`. This has never worked for me because my containers only seem to contain the result of the last build step that succeeded. Can anyone tell me how to debug my fully built container?

Comment: docker exec in a container will show only the results of that container instance. Please elaborate more on what you mean by fully built container ? and what specifically you want to debug ?

Comment: What commands have you already run?  Can you give an example of what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the interactive parameter

Try:

```
docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash
```

or

```
docker exec -it container_id bash
```

In case you are using an alpine based container use

```
docker exec -it container_id sh
```

With docker compose you can do the same with:

`docker-compose exec <service_name> bash`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your containers are up or not.
If they are not, this command won't work as your container is down, so you can use "-verbose" when starting the container: docker-comppose up --verbose. 
If your container is up, it's probably because your image doesn't contain the binary bash. On which image is your container base?